# Using MouseMove() with Status Bar

Tags: vb6, statusbar, mousemove

I have been searching for an answer on Stack Overflow and on Google but found nothing. I am doing this as a school project and can not get my head around it. i need the status bar to show "Ready" when the mouse is not over the text boxes. This is the code for one of the text boxes:

```
Private Sub Text3_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
StatusBar1.SimpleText = "Last Name of Student"
End Sub
```

How can I make it that when the mouse is somewhere else it says "Ready".

Thanks to anyone that could help.

Comment: The easy way would be to add a MouseMove handler for the form and use that to set 'Ready'.  If it were my application I would use ToolTipText and only update the status bar when the control has focus using the GotFocus and LostFocus events.  With the way you have it, if the user moves the mouse then they may lose the help text for the textbox they are currently using.  Using GotFocus and LostFocus means that won't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a `mousemove` for every object on the screen and coded it to show the information on the status bar.